# AcitveRecord - Map exsisting Row id to Class Record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have 3 tables:

Table 1:

[image: table1]

Table 2:

[image: table2]

Table 3:

[image: table3]

Table1.cat == Table2.id
Table1.adtype == Table3.id

Table 2's and Table 3's rows preexist and are not create when a new row from Table 1 is created. Rows from Table 2 and Table 3 should not depend on rows from Table 1.

Using ActiveRecord in Rails 4, how do I map these correct so the row data from Table 2 and Table 3 is loaded through association?

Assuming the Class for Table 1 is `test`, I want to be able to do `test.classname` and have it show `Fairway Woods`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
belongs_to :classtypes, :foreign_key => :adtype
belongs_to :classcat, :foreign_key => :cat
```

This did the trick for me